# Running a tool via a bash script

Tags: bash, slurm

I am trying to make a bash script that I want to run on a cluster. I want to run a tool a several times. I am trying to run tool called discoal several times and each time I am running this tool on a given script 'run_Script.dis'.
Is this the right way to do it. Will this allow me to use multi-threading?

I've attached the code as well.

```py
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --partition normal
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu 12G
#SBATCH -c 1
#SBATCH -t 2:00:00

source activate tool
for i in {1..2331}
do
    sbatch -p express '/home/user/build/discoal /home/user/run_script.dis'
done
```

Comment: I think this could stand a good chance of getting reopened if you can clarify it. See my comments on the current answer. If you want to ask about Slurm specifically, probably be more explicit that Bash is just a component of your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no multi-threading in bash. What you can do to achive something like that is to run commands in the background by use `&` at the end of the command.

```
for i in {1..2331}
do
    sbatch -p express '/home/user/build/discoal /home/user/run_script.dis' &
done
wait
```

Keep in mind this code will spawn 2331 subshell run the `sbatch -p express '/home/user/build/discoal /home/user/run_script.dis'` command in very short amount of time. This might cause performance issues, if you still want to go with it, I would recommend to change the priority of the command by `nice`.

`wait` command requires to tell the main script to wait all background process to complete.

There is a `parallel` command what do care about how many cpu you have so not start all of the 2331 process at the same time. Unfortunately I not familiar with it yet, so I cannot give you an example.

Comment: I'm guessing `sbatch` schedules the command to run on different cluster nodes, so backgrounding this basically achieves nothing, and the OP is already accomplishing true parallelism by running the code on multiple computers. But I have no exposure to Slurm so this is guesswork at this point.

Comment: But yeah, definitely no threading here. Probably the OP really means "will this run in parallel", not "will this use threading."